# Custom filter for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an application with many user roles. Like `Admin`, `Manager` etc.

There are some instances where both `Manager` and `Admin` has the same permission to see/edit a page. 
In the `route.php` I created a filter group for Admin access only.

```
//filter.php
    Route::filter('admin', function()
    {
        if (Auth::guest() or ! Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
            return 'Not Authorized';
        }
    });
```

```
//route.php
  Route::group(['before' => 'admin'], function(){
    //Some routes.....
  });
```

Now, I want to check if the user is allowed to view that page by checking the `userId` and the `courseId`. How can I get these values in the `filter.php`?

I have a function which checks if the user is authorized for that page. But it requires two variables to be passed (Atleast one variable, the `courseId`)

```
public static function isAllowed($userId, $courseId){
//Some conditions. 
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @lukasgeiter, you might wanna take a look at this.

Comment: Well well... guess I'm too late ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy actually. In `filter.php` you simply need to add your filter function and then use it on the `routes.php`

To Decalre a filter for `Route::get('my/url/{variable1}/{variable2})`:

```
Route::filter('myAweSomeFilter', function($route)
{
    $variable1 = $route->getParameter('variable1');
    if (thisAndThat)
    {
        doStuff;
    }
});
```

now, If you want to call a model function, you can do that inside this function.

Therefore, if you have a model named `AuthModel`, and a static function named `coursePermissionCheck`, simply call it as `AuthModel::coursePermisssionCheck()` and so on. You also write a whole new function inside of the filter function and use it. It's just another function that tells the RouteController what to do if a certain condition is not met.

How to use this filter: `'before' => 'admin|youFilter'`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you haven't got my question. Sorry about that. What if I need to get some variables from the URL and use it in the filter.php ?

Comment: I have a URL like this: `example.com/courses/123/show`

From this URL, how can I get the `123` in the `filter.php` ?

Comment: It says the variable `$course` is undefined. In the filter.php

Comment: Phew. I was way off the course.  Glad I didn't screw up bad =)